# What client manager for postgres do you use? Phpmyadmin analog for postgres

Tags: postgresql, client

colud you tell me what client manager do you use for postgres? I tried phppgadmin and desktop pgadmin but they have a lot of functionality limitations comparing to what phpmyadmin or heidiSql can do for mysql. I'm just wondering is there any good tool for postgres? What do you use?

Comment: What limitations? And what is your personal definition of "a good tool" ? Without your requirements it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: well let's rephrase: "Could you advise a tool for postgres you use except phppgadmin, pgadmin or console pgsql?"

Comment: Check the wiki page: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools